# What's difference in JS between document.getElementsbyID & document.stylesheets[0].rules[0]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get Mouse X,Y and set them to my.css file's customvalue

```
:root{
--mouse-x:0px;
}
```

in ejs file, it load css file `<link ~ my.css id="mcss">`
and

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementByID('mcss');
<--Get Mouse X, save to var x-->
el.style.setProperty('--mouse-x',x+"px");
</script>
```

But It doesn't works well
When I tried with document.stylesheets[0].rules[0] it works well.
What's the difference?

Comment: There is no `document.getElementByID`. Did you mean [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)?

Comment: you are setting a property to a `<link>` element which is not logical

Comment: This might be helpful on how to find custom attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763121/list-css-custom-properties-css-variables/45763800#45763800

Comment: Single line script comments are marked by `//` not HTML delimiters.