# Get all CSS variables on an HTML element with JavaScript when you don't know the names of the CSS Variables?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, css-variables

In JavaScript I need to read all the CSS vars that have been applied to an HTML element.

If I know the name of a CSS variable eg `--thing` I can get it's value with this code. This works in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
  const elem = document.querySelector("html");
  if (!elem) return;
  const style = getComputedStyle(elem);
  const myVariable = style.getPropertyValue("--thing");
  console.log({ myVariable });
```

I've tried iterating over the properties and looking for names that start with `--`. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
    const propertyName = style[i];
    if (propertyName.startsWith("--")) {
      console.log(propertyName);
    }
  }
```

Is there a solution that works cross browser or at least in Chrome?

UPDATE. Im not able to post an answer but this works in Firefox and Chrome (might not be the best solution)

```
  const res: Record<string, string> = {};

  if ("computedStyleMap" in elem) {
    // Chrome
    const styles = elem.computedStyleMap();
    Array.from(styles).forEach(([prop, val]) => {
      if (prop.startsWith("--")) {
        res[prop] = val.toString();
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Firefox
    const styles = getComputedStyle(elem);
    for (let i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
      const propertyName = styles[i];
      if (propertyName.startsWith("--")) {
        const value = styles.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
        res[propertyName] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log({ res });
```

Comment: I will note that most of the answers in the [List CSS custom properties (CSS Variables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763121/list-css-custom-properties-css-variables) alleged duplicate rely on attempting to parse a stylesheet as text, which seems quite fraught.  The [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004635/how-to-list-all-css-variables-names-values-pairs-from-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004635/how-to-list-all-css-variables-names-values-pairs-from-element) solution, however, has some more robust options.

Comment: @AlexanderNied It seems  that the answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004635/how-to-list-all-css-variables-names-values-pairs-from-element relies on getMatchedCSSRules which appears to no longer exist.

Comment: `startsWith` is deprecated. Use something else

Comment: @Plantt — can you provide a source for that?  Per [MDN's `startsWith()` reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#browser_compatibility) it is supported in all major browsers without any plans to deprecate noted...

Comment: @AHaworth — good catch, thanks for calling that out.

Comment: @evanss have the duplicates fully answered your question? One doesn’t work nowadays and the others don’t seem to deal with anything but variables set in stylesheets and then for :root. Do you need to look at other elements and/or inline styling?

Comment: @AlexanderNied Agreed I don't like the idea of parsing stylesheets.

Comment: @AHaworth Ideally yes I would be able to specify the element. Normally it will be root but not always.

Comment: So, being picky, the duplicates don’t answer the question, and as I don’t ‘normally’ set variables in :root but only within their required scope I would also be interested in an answer so voting to reopen.

Comment: I'm also voting to reopen— I think a more modern solution to 2024 would be appreciated (or a confirmation that none is possible).

Comment: @evanss glad you found methods for Chrome and FF. If we can't get this q. reopened perhaps you could add  your answer to one of the alleged duplicates so at least one of the the closure reasons given becomes true.

Comment: @AlexanderNied if you're looking for a newer answer, a bounty on an existing question would be the correct approach

Comment: @AlexanderNied I was coding something in TS and it showed up as deprecated, it's not reliable ig